# **breeding ground** VS **hotbed**

Tags: prepositions, word-difference

> 1. Without regulation, the Internet would become a **breeding ground** for/of crime.
> 2. Without regulation, the Internet would become a **hotbed** for/of crime.

My first question is whether the two above sentence have the same meaning. My second queation is whether *of* or *for* is followed by *ground* and *hotbed*?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The sentences have nearly the same meaning but aren't exactly equivalent. An online **breeding ground** for crime suggests a site where criminals meet and plan exploits to carry out on the Internet *or in real life*.

In slight contrast, a **hotbed** of crime suggests that the crimes are predominately occurring on the Internet; that is, the crime is mostly cybercrime.

Depending on the context, the difference may be negligible.

The prepositions given above ("for", "of") are the ones most commonly used with the corresponding phrases. (The other preposition could also be used for each, but this usage is less common by about an order of magnitude according to an online search.)